# TCP Packet loss after Azure load balancer

Tags: networking, nat, azure-load-balancer, packet-loss, azure-public-ip

If we have one VM after the **Azure load balancer** (external) at first. The TCP connection will be routed to VM1.

```
--connection1 packet--> Azure Load Balancer (20.20.20.20) --connection1 packet--> VM1
```

Then we add a new VM after the lb.

```
--connection1 packet--> Azure Load Balancer (20.20.20.20) ----> VM1 
                                                          --connection1 packet--> VM2
```

Normally the connection would still be routed to VM1 as there is **connection tracking**. But this is not guranteed because the Azure load balancer is implemented as a distributed software load balancer as described in this [article](https://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2013/papers/sigcomm/p207.pdf).

So the packet **might** be routed to VM2. The expected behaviour is that the packet could get inside VM2 and gets a TCP **RST** to end this connection. But it turns out the packet would be **dropped** before it gets inside VM2.

I hope to know why this packet is dropped. Is it because the NAT?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the article, and I am not sure that I am correctly spotting the reason:
The reason may be based on the Traffic Manager routing methods of azure. As in the article, they 've used a weighted random load policy. You can make look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods) for reference to various methods of handling traffic methods.

I am not damn sure, I just replied maybe this could be the reason.